# .dir-local.el misunderstanding

Tags: local-variables, directory-local-variables

I generated a `.dir-locals.el` by calling the function `add-dir-local-variable`, giving it the path for the project for which I want the variable, the variable itself, and its value.

The generated file went to my home directory (not the project path as I expected), and had the following content:

```
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

(("~/tmp/test_test_dir_local"
  (indent-tabs-mode . t)))
```

Then I went on and created a file `a.c` in that directory, and copied `.dir-locals.el` there for good measure.

The indent in that file is still set as spaces, as per my `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. I expected it to be tabs, as per the local `.dir-locals.el`. I tried restarting emacs, but that did not work either.

What did I do wrong, or misunderstand?

I am on Mac OS Sierra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `add-dir-local-variable`, it assumes you are already in the directory you want to apply the directory-local variable to. When it prompts for a directory, it's asking if you want the variable applied to a *subdirectory* of your current directory.

So I expect giving it the *absolute* path to a directory is causing your problem. In your case, I think what you need is a `.dir-locals.el` file in the directory you're targeting (i.e., `~/tmp/test_test_dir_local`) that contains the following:

```
((nil
  (indent-tabs-mode . t)))
```

The `nil` symbol indicates that this variable will be applied to all files in all subdirectories of the `~/tmp/test_test_dir_local`. You can change it to indicate you only want it applied to a certain subdirectory (in quotes):

```
(("src"
  (indent-tabs-mode . t)))
```

Or a particular major mode (no quotes):

```
((c-mode
  (indent-tabs-mode . t)))
```

Comment: That was it. I could have guessed that the file in a path, and asking for a path was the fishy thing. Thanks!